# Best way to put Live xml data into S3 and run java code to parse and create text file

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cloud

I am live xml files coming out of Tibco message queue .
The size of the xml file varies from 5KB to 10 MB and number of xml per minutes is 20 .

I am parsing all these xml and creating text file and then creating EMR cluster and run my spark job for analytics .
I am running my spark job once in a week .

There are two ways that i can perform this .

**WAY One:** I will store all these xml outside AWS cloud and and then will run my java code to parse it and will compress it and then i will upload into S3 .
In this case i will keep on accumulating all xml for a day and then will run java code to parse .
Also i will wait for 15 days then upload all text file into s3 whenever i nedd to run my Spark EMR job .

**WAY TWO:** I will direct my tibco queue into s3 using direct connect and then invoke EC2 instance and will parse XML and again will load back to S3 .

Which out of this two is better way in terms of better designing and cost?

Answer (score 1):

I would use `SQS` for communication between Tibco, and AWS. That way, if your XML is smaller then 256kB then it will go only with queue message. In other cases `S3` will be used, so message will have reference to `S3 object`. After consuming, all is removed automatically. You can use spot instances to deal with that messages, to have it cheaper. There is something like dead letter queue, so problematic messages will be stored for later investigation.

I see there are samples how to integrate SQS and Tibco, so should not be much work with it. A specially if you have integration with S3.

Comment: Thanks for the info but i would like o know which way is better any why ?

Comment: If you store outside AWS inbound transfer will cost you. Also that is known to be slower. Question is about your costs... Anyway I would try to put all the things into AWS and operate there. That way you have infra as a service - and can setup another one for testing, with low costs. I would also switch to event processing model as wrote. That will give your code better scalability, and some problems will be fixed out of the box.

Comment: Sorry for late reply I was doing some research ...Order of the message is very important in my case .Either I have to consume all from the queue or we have to store in the folder in the same order as in the queue .But as you said size limit is 256 KB but I have messages that have 10mb of size also .

Comment: Order can be forced. So you can be sure that it goes like normal FIFO queue. If message is big then it's body is stored in S3, and message has only reference to that S3 object. Java driver deals with it under the hood, so for you it is transparent.